# Alignment shifts after specific width

Tags: css

I am helping with the port of a site to a new server.  All of this is inherited code.  An example page is this one:  http://fcxcobalt.fmi.com/products/

This heading:

```
<h1 class="main-content-heading"><span class="wrapper">Products</span></h1>
```

At screen widths less than 1690px the heading aligns as desired:

[image]

But at 1690px and higher widths the element left aligns to the body of the document.

The heading's own CSS may not be the issue but it is

```
.main-content-heading {
  margin: 0 0 1.2em;
  padding: 0.5em 0;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #fff;
  background: #1c3f94;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

Unminified CSS can be seen here:  http://pastebin.com/s5MVMZVj

Can anyone advise me as to how this alignment can be made consistent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are seeing here is the result of a media query in the CSS:

```
@media screen and (min-width:1707px){
    .wrapper,.page-head,.site-menu,.droplets,.wide-content{
        margin:0 auto
    }

}

@media screen and (max-width:1040px){
    .wrapper,.page-head,.site-menu,.droplets,.wide-content{
        margin:0 3%
    }

    .bx-aspect-wrapper{
        margin-bottom:-10em
    }

    .bx-pager{
        right:3%
    }

    .bx-slide-caption,.bx-prev,.bx-next{
        font-size:130%
    }

}
```

The switch over takes place at 1707px (you estimated 1690px, well spotted!).

This is an example of a responsive design, and my guess is that the designer wanted to keep some left/right margin for smaller screens where as `margin: 0 auto` would lead to the margins collapsing all together.

There is nothing wrong with your browser and the CSS is working as intended.

Of course, the sharp transition may be a bit unsightly to some.

This might be made smoother by setting `margin: 0 Mpx` where M is a magical number of pixels that might be close to (1707px - {page layout width in px})/2, but you would have to try it to see.

**Fixing Layout Glitch for Widths Greater Than 1707px**

I found that if I leave out the `margin: 0 auto` declaration in the following CSS snippet, the "Product" label stays where it is suppose to.

I tested this in Firefox only.

```
@media screen and (min-width:1707px){
    .wrapper,.page-head,.site-menu,.droplets,.wide-content{
       margin:0 auto
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response!  I may not have phrased my question clearly- I am hoping to keep the header permanently aligned with the menuing and page content.  I am guessing given the structure that this would involve targeting the contained span but I am at a loss as to how to give it left padding that always matches.

Comment: @jerrygarciuh I reread your question and re-examined the CSS and realized that to see the layout problem, you need a very large screen and my laptop screen was not wide enough.  I see the problem and I think I now how to fix it, but will get back to it tomorrow morning.

Comment: Thank you so very much!  I would never have found it!

Comment: You are very welcome!  I think that the CSS glitch was an oversight by the original developer.  The media query in question does not seem to do much, maybe it was not fully tested.  Regardless, you are now in a good position to deal with it.  All the best!